# Add new line to String.Join?

Tags: c#, string

So I've been trying like crazy to add a new line to my `String.Join` printout but it seems it's not possible or Am i doing something wrong ? I've both tried using `"/n/r"` and `Enivrorment.NewLine` as well as a making a class too create a new line

list box I'm trying to print out too

```
ListBox1.Items.Add("Calories to lose 0.5kg per week: " +
    string.Join(Environment.NewLine + "Calories to lose 1kg per week:",
        bc.LoseOrGainWeightCalories(bc.MaintainWightCalories(), true)));
```

calling on this class:

```
public string[] LoseOrGainWeightCalories(double weight, bool lose) {
    string[] array = new string[2];
    double LoseGainWeight = this.weight;
    if(lose==true) {
        array[0] = Convert.ToString(LoseGainWeight - 500);
        array[1] = Convert.ToString(LoseGainWeight - 1000);
    } else {
        array[0] = Convert.ToString(LoseGainWeight + 500);
        array[1] = Convert.ToString(LoseGainWeight + 1000);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Picture of current output:

[image]

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: 2 Seperate lines : one for 0.5Kg and one line under that for 1kg , but the current output is nexttoo eachother

Comment: that is not how to put text on separate "lines" in a Listbox

Comment: Take a look at verbatim string in c# (like @"")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is not with the `String.Join` method:

```
$ csharp
csharp> string.Join(Environment.NewLine + "Calories to lose 1kg per week:",new double[] {13,21});
"13
Calories to lose 1kg per week:21"
```

The problem thus lies with the `ListBox` that does not render new lines. You can solve with two different solutions:

1. **Add multiple items** as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354533/how-to-put-a-nnew-line-inside-a-list-box)

So you could thus add each line as a new item. The problem with this approach is that **the user can select a single line** unless you are willing to write a solution to prevent that.

You can thus perform:

```
string s = "Calories to lose 0.5kg per week: " +
string.Join(Environment.NewLine + "Calories to lose 1kg per week:",
    bc.LoseOrGainWeightCalories(bc.MaintainWightCalories(), true));
foreach (string si in Regex.Split(s,"\n"))
    ListBox1.Items.Add(si);
```

2. **Write a renderer that writes one element with a multiple lines** as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360871/can-listbox-items-span-multiple-lines-c-sharp).

(copied the essential parts)

```
ListBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
private void listBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e) {
    int i = e.Index;
    float heightLine = 10.0f;
    string lines = listBox1.Items[i].ToString()Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.None).Length;
    e.ItemHeight = (int) Math.Ceil(heightLine*itemi);
}
private void listBox1_DrawItem (object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
   e.DrawBackground();
   e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds);
}
ListBox1.MeasureItem += listBox1_MeasureItem;
ListBox1.DrawItem += listBox1_DrawItem;
```

Comment: Thanks for the Edit the first one worked perfectly! :) I hadn't reached my upvote yet but it worked out great and I understand what you ment and what you did :)