# New line "\n" does not work yet no errors are given

Tags: c++-cli

I have a program that loads a checked list box, then the user selects the items they want and selects a button to say they are done. The checked items are read in a contiguous string with a newline "\n" at the end of each string added. My problem is everything works ok except the newline "\n", and I don't know why.

Code

```
private: System::Void bntSelected_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

    int numSelected = this->checkedListBox1->CheckedItems->Count;

    if (numSelected != 0)
    {
        // Set input focus to the list box.
        //SetFocus(lstReceiver);
        String^ listBoxStr = "";
        // If so, loop through all checked items and print results.  
        for (int x = 0; x < numSelected; x++)
        {
            listBoxStr = listBoxStr + (x + 1).ToString() + " = " + this->checkedListBox1->CheckedItems[x]->ToString() + "\n";
        }
        lstReceiver->Items->Add(listBoxStr);
    }
}
```

Comment: `String^ listBoxStr ` How can this compile? Are you sure it's C++, not other programming language?

Comment: What do you mean by "\n does not work"?

Comment: Yes it is C++ and by "\n" does not work is it does not put a newline at the end of each read.

Comment: Maybe you should add the strings one by one with Add  and not append them all in one long string before adding.

Comment: I loaded them one at a time, and that works well.

Answer (score 0):

The string is being formed correctly, but the `ListBox` control doesn't show newlines in its list items - each item is pushed onto a single line. You can see this by debugging, or by adding a `Label` to the form with `AutoSize` set to false - the label will show the newline(s) in the string properly.

Related (C#): [How to put a \n(new line) inside a list box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354533/how-to-put-a-nnew-line-inside-a-list-box)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of ‘\n’, try ‘\r\n’. This may be a windows thing.